# contest inequality problem

Tags: inequality, contest-math

Let $a\geq0$, $b\geq0$ and $c\ge 0$. Prove that: $$\sum_{cyc} \frac{a}{a^2b+1}\ge \frac{3\sqrt[3]{abc}}{1+abc}.$$

Comment: is this a cyclic sum?

Comment: yes it is a cyclic sum.

Comment: Please edit the cyclic sum into your question (maybe even write it out in full). & please add some context & thoughts of your own.

Comment: is any additional condition given?

Answer (score 1):

I think it's wrong. Try $a=c=2$ and $b=\frac{1}{4}$.

Comment: i think there is an additionally condition missing

Comment: Sonnhard The answer is no I think. Because there is a very nice similar reversed inequality without condition.